# javascript implement function inside function to call directly

Tags: javascript

i have an included javascript like this (and it cannot be edit)

```
db.profile.loadInitProperties({
    "url": "http://www.google.com",
    "path": "/search",
    "temp": true,
});
```

so i make my own function to make it work but not luck.

```
function db(profile) {
    this.profile = function (properties) {
        this.properties = function (string) {
            //do sth
        }
    }
}
```

always got `"TypeError: db.profile.properties is not a function"`.

Is there anyway to make it work?

Comment: what you want to do exactly ?? what do you mean by (cannot be edit)?

Comment: Are you looking to create a [class in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)? I agree with @spankajd - this question is vague and I'm having difficult time understanding exactly what it is you are looking for...

Comment: im new to javascript sorry. 
@anied I just want to get information from 
db.profile.loadInitProperties (this code i include from another domain so i dont have permision to edit).
maybe create class or object to match with that call but i dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript a class is basically a function. If you have a function and you would like to use it as an object rather than a function, you'll need to new an object first.

```
function db(profile){
    this.profile = profile;
}
var _db = new db(profile);
console.log(_db.profile);
```

If you only call db.profile this will not work.

Comment: Tks for reply. but all i need is to get info when db.profile.loadInitProperties run. but cannot know how to implement